# Maven GWT Plugin : CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: maven, gwt, artifactory

I created a simple Project with default archtype with this command :

`mvn -B archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin -DarchetypeVersion=2.5.1 -DgroupId=org.dpdouran.web -DartifactId=WebERP   -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT     -Dmodule=WebERP`

then I added my artifactory repository address and some dependencies to the POM. no other things I changed.

The problem is before adding dependencies when I run `mvn clean package` it gives me a working war but after adding dependencies I get this error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1:i18n (default) on project WebERP: Failed to execute command line :
[ERROR] [-Xmx512m, -classpath, C:\Users\localUser\hbl\t1\WebERP\src\main\java;C:\Users\localUser\hbl\t1\WebERP\src\main\resources;
...
C:\Users\localUser\.m2\repository\org\dpdouran\support\support\94049\support-94049.jar;C:\Users\localUser\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-user\2.5.1\gwt-user-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\localUser\.m2\repository\com\google\gwt\gwt-dev\2.5.1\gwt-dev-2.5.1.jar, com.google.gwt.i18n.tools.I18NSync, -out, C:\Users\localUser\hbl\t1\WebERP\target\generated-sources\gwt, -createMessages, org.dpdouran.web.client.Messages]: Error while executing process. Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=206, 
The filename or extension is too long
```

Here is my POM :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.dpdouran.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebERP</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>WebERP</name>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>DouranArtifacts</id>
      <name>DouranArtifacts</name>
      <url>http://192.168.100.243:8082/artifactory/DouranArtifacts/</url>
    </repository>

  </distributionManagement>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>DouranArtifacts</id>
      <name>DouranArtifacts</name>
      <url>http://192.168.100.243:8082/artifactory/DouranArtifacts/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
    <!-- Convenience property to set the GWT version -->
    <gwtVersion>2.5.1</gwtVersion>
    <!-- GWT needs at least java 1.5 -->
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- added by Habil-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>joutlookbar_demo</artifactId>
      <version>joutlookbar_demo</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
      <version>jpa</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsqlparser</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lookandfeel</artifactId>
      <version>55578</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-icu</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-kuromoji</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-morfologik</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-phonetic</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-smartcn</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-stempel</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-uima</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-facet</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
      <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>microba</artifactId>
      <version>0.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>mondrian</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.12687</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>morena</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>morena_license</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>morena_windows</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>morfologik-ukrainian-search</artifactId>
      <version>3.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>oa</artifactId>
      <version>86329</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>ofcgwt</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
      <version>8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>outlook</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
      <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>production</artifactId>
      <version>67435</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>proguard</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>requestfactory-apt</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>requestfactory-client</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>requestfactory-server</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>rex</artifactId>
      <version>20070125</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>simplecaptcha</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqleonardo</artifactId>
      <version>200703</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId>
      <version>42</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>toplink-essentials</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>toplink-essentials-agent</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>websocket-api</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>wmf2svg</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>wordapi</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.04</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.thirdparty</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmltools</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.financial</groupId>
      <artifactId>accounting</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Attendanc</artifactId>
      <version>990814</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Command</artifactId>
      <version>990814</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Common</artifactId>
      <version>990814</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Evaluation</artifactId>
      <version>990814</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_PayRoll</artifactId>
      <version>990814</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Personnel</artifactId>
      <version>990814</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Pishnehadat</artifactId>
      <version>990814</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Recruitment</artifactId>
      <version>990814</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Refahi</artifactId>
      <version>990814</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>HR_Training</artifactId>
      <version>990814</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebHumanResource</artifactId>
      <version>990719</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.hr</groupId>
      <artifactId>organizationchart</artifactId>
      <version>990814</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>ErpWebService</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>FileManager</artifactId>
      <version>94381</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebAnalytic</artifactId>
      <version>94324</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebCommon</artifactId>
      <version>94387</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebDashboard</artifactId>
      <version>89985</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebDav</artifactId>
      <version>85722</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebFileManager</artifactId>
      <version>94966</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebInfra</artifactId>
      <version>94977</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebInfraMultiLang</artifactId>
      <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>cartable</artifactId>
      <version>86854</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>coding</artifactId>
      <version>61039</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>common</artifactId>
      <version>94720</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>db</artifactId>
      <version>56510</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>infra</artifactId>
      <version>94935</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>reporting</artifactId>
      <version>94158</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>webcartable</artifactId>
      <version>92374</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>weboa</artifactId>
      <version>93929</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>webskin</artifactId>
      <version>94958</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>webworkflow</artifactId>
      <version>86081</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.infra</groupId>
      <artifactId>workflow</artifactId>
      <version>94228</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.logistics</groupId>
      <artifactId>realestate</artifactId>
      <version>63853</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.logistics</groupId>
      <artifactId>risk_management</artifactId>
      <version>73541</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.monitoring</groupId>
      <artifactId>NetworkCommon</artifactId>
      <version>94261</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.monitoring</groupId>
      <artifactId>NetworkGraph</artifactId>
      <version>94286</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.monitoring</groupId>
      <artifactId>NetworkMonitoringUI</artifactId>
      <version>94299</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.monitoring</groupId>
      <artifactId>NetworkUtil</artifactId>
      <version>94543</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.monitoring</groupId>
      <artifactId>NetworkWebService</artifactId>
      <version>89589</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.monitoring</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebNetworkDiscovery</artifactId>
      <version>92079</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.monitoring</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebNetworkMonitoring</artifactId>
      <version>94597</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.monitoring</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebStockChart</artifactId>
      <version>94597</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebSupport</artifactId>
      <version>92325</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectmanagement</artifactId>
      <version>93256</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dpdouran.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support</artifactId>
      <version>94049</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Generate compiled stuff in the folder used for developing mode -->
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
              <goal>i18n</goal>
              <goal>generateAsync</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see 
          gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
        <configuration>
          <runTarget>WebERP.html</runTarget>
          <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
          <i18nMessagesBundle>org.dpdouran.web.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Copy static web files before executing gwt:run -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exploded</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I Have to use GWT 2.5.1 and java 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classpath argument for compiling the GWT component is too long for Windows shell to handle.

Most dependencies appear to be server-side components of the webapp, and really should not be present in the classpath when compiling the GWT client-side component of the webapp.

One solution is to split the webapp into 2 maven submodules, one for the client and one for the server.  This approach is considered "best practice" in the GWT community, and is well supported by the TBroyer GWT maven plugin, which supersedes the Mojo GWT maven plugin that you are using.  Refer to https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin and for archetypes https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes

Comment: My shared classes use server-side annotations like Hibernate or just non-nullness. I would suppose these are not needed for JS generation but they still require server-side libs in classpath. I could not find a way to ignore them in GWT compiler. Is it possible?

Comment: One way is to structure your project in the "modern"/recommended way, with he client and server side parts in separate maven modules.  Refer to https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/

Comment: These shared classes are used both in client and server, and they contain server side annotations. Even if I move them to a separate project the GWT compiler will need the annotation jars in classpath (which I hoped to avoid). Anyway in my case I rectified the CodeServer classpath leaving only my sources, GWT 3rd party libs and server side annotations - that helped a lot.